# BTRFS: scrub finds "super" errors - how to fix them?

Tags: btrfs, scrub

I've recently had problems with a faulty power supply to a Raspberry PI system used as a media center. Before tracking it and replacing with a new power unit it seems it did some damages to an old disk (that could be troubled by itself) and to a not so old disk that is physically ok. It's formatted with btrfs and scrub gives errors in "super":

```
# btrfs scrub status -d /dev/sda1
scrub status for **************************
scrub device /dev/sda1 (id 1) history
    scrub resumed at Mon Feb  1 22:55:03 2021 and finished after 01:44:48
    total bytes scrubbed: 160.77GiB with 2 errors
    error details: super=2
    corrected errors: 0, uncorrectable errors: 0, unverified errors: 0
```

btrfs check doesn't find any problem:

```
# btrfs check --progress /dev/sda1
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/sda1
UUID: **************************
[1/7] checking root items                      (0:00:00 elapsed, 36660 items checked)
[2/7] checking extents                         (0:00:26 elapsed, 16745 items checked)
[3/7] checking free space cache                (0:00:06 elapsed, 240 items checked)
[4/7] checking fs roots                        (0:00:32 elapsed, 684 items checked)
[5/7] checking csums (without verifying data)  (0:00:29 elapsed, 35432 items checked)
[6/7] checking root refs                       (0:00:00 elapsed, 3 items checked)
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 252808790016 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 246555120
total tree bytes: 274219008
total fs tree bytes: 11255808
total extent tree bytes: 3080192
btree space waste bytes: 11029386
file data blocks allocated: 252534571008
 referenced 252534571008
```

Now, given that I do have a full backup and an automated script to sync to the media center, so the less troubling thing would be to reformat and populate the disk, I think it's a good context to make some experiment. So: is there any way to attempt a fix?

Thanks.